# Not showing output python, no error showing

Tags: python-3.x

Let us consider polynomials in a single variable x with integer coefficients: for instance, 3x^4 - 17x^2 - 3x + 5.  Each term of the polynomial can be represented as a pair of integers (coefficient,exponent).  The polynomial itself is then a list of such pairs.

We have the following constraints to guarantee that each polynomial has a unique representation:

- Terms are sorted in descending order of exponent
- No term has a zero coefficient
- No two terms have the same exponent
- Exponents are always nonnegative

For example, the polynomial introduced earlier is represented as

[(3,4),(-17,2),(-3,1),(5,0)]

The zero polynomial, 0, is represented as the empty list [], since it has no terms with nonzero coefficients.

Write Python functions for the following operations:

addpoly(p1,p2) ?

```
def addpoly(p1,p2):
    p1=[]
    p2=[]
    for i in range(0,len(p1)):
        for j in range(0,len(p2)):
            L=[]

            if p1[i][1]==p2[j][1]:
                L=L[p1[i][0]+p2[j][0]][p1[i][1]]
            elif p1[i][1]!=p2[j][1]:
                L=L+p1[i][j]
                L=L+p2[i][j]
        print("L")
```

Comment: Please indent your code, as of now it is hard to see what you are trying to achieve. Another thing you are printing "L" in the end is that the intention or do you want to print the list L instead?

Comment: You are reassigning p1 and p2 to empty lists at the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the p1 and p2 arguments to empty lists at the top of your function. This means you will always be checking `for i in range(0, 0)`, which is an empty range. In other words, nothing in your loop will be executed. This is why you are not seeing any output. You are not seeing any error messages, because there is nothing wrong with your syntax, the problem is with the logic.

My math skills are nonexistent, so I cannot comment on the accuracy of most of the logic in your code, but for sure you need to get rid of the first two lines of your function (`p1 = []` and `p2 = []`) or your function will do nothing.

Also, make sure to print the variable `L` rather than the string `"L"` to print your list:

```
print(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
def addpoly(p1,p2):
    L=[]
    for i in range(0,len(p1)):
        for j in range(0,len(p2)):
            if p1[i][1] == p2[j][1] and p1[i][0]+p2[j][0] != 0 :
                L.append((p1[i][0]+p2[j][0],p1[i][1]))
            elif p1[i][1] == p2[j][1] and p1[i][0]+p2[j][0] == 0 :
                pass
            elif i == j:
                L.append(p2[i])
                L.append(p1[i])

    return (L)
```